# VBA-excel: How to check if any of controls were changed

Tags: vba, excel

Im new at VBA and wonder if there any way to check if any of `UserForm` `controls` were changed? Maybe there is some global event handler for all of  controls?

For example I have a `UserForm1` with some data and `Controls` on it. Also there is some kind of global Boolean `B_bool` which is `False` by default.

If User changes any text or click any of radio buttons, or check any of checkboxes `B_bool` becomes True.

I tried to create some sort of event handler and a Classmodule for each type of controls but only textbox and optionbuttons classes work fine. Other classes (checkboxes, comboboxes) swears at OnChange event (Object or class doesn't support the set of events)

Following code mostly same for every type of control, so i see no reason to flood a question

```
Private WithEvents MyTextBox As MSForms.TextBox

Public Property Set Control(tb As MSForms.TextBox)
    Set MyTextBox = tb
End Property

Private Sub MyTextBox_Change()
   B_bool = True
End Sub
```

and then UserForm code

```
Public tbCollection As Collection

    Private Sub Userform_Initialize()
    Set tbCollection = New Collection   
     For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
            If TypeOf ctrl Is MSForms.TextBox Then
                Set obj_tb = New clsTextBox
                Set obj_tb.Control = ctrl
                tbCollection.Add obj_tb
            End If 
    Next ctrl
    End Sub
```

Comment: In what way are you expecting controls to change?  Are you referring to the *values* alone?  Do you just want a single overall `TRUE`/`FALSE` that "something changed", or more specific?

Comment: Yes, only one thing True or False nothing else. One Global varriable for all controls. I want to create something like "Document was changed. Do you want to save changes?" for userform with my data

Comment: aha - that changes things.  You question has a common fault known as the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) - asking about your attempted *solution* rather than the actual *problem*.  I'm glad you clarified before I wasted time writing unnecessary code... I won't get into the semantics of that -- the short version is: Excel already tracks whether the sheet has unsaved changes, so you can just "ask Excel." Now, is there any reason it has to look *only* at your userform, or is it okay if it tell you if anything in the workbook changed?

Comment: Im sorry for that

Comment: no problem, you didn't know. (I'm trying to remember to consider that possibility.)  But there was a question in there. :)   Regardless, I'll attempt an Answer an you can see if it works for you.

Comment: For a checkbox, it's a click event. Take a look at this post of mine: http://yoursumbuddy.com/userform-event-class-multiple-control-types/

Answer (score 0):

You can detect if a workbook has unsaved changes with:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Saved
```

An example of how you could use this:

```
'Here is the code where your userform is prepared for the user...
'maybe you set default values or something like that.  Once you're
'finished the changes YOU (or your VBA) are making to the workbook,
'SAVE it.  This will mark a "starting point" to watch for changes...

 ActiveWorkbook.Save

'And here would be your code (if any) that runs when the user is doing
'he does.  blah blah blah
'When it's time to check if the user made any changes, find out with:

If ActiveWorkbook.Saved then
    'no changes have been made
Else
    'changes have been made
    'do whatever you need to do to save your data.
End If
```

See the links below to learn how `AutoSave` may or may not affect this functionality.

---

### More Information:

- MSDN : [Workbook.Saved Property (Excel/VBA)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-saved-property-excel)
- MSDN : [Workbook.Save Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-save-method-excel)
- MSDN : [Workbook.AutoSaveOn Property (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-autosaveon-property-excel)
- MSDN : [How AutoSave impacts add-ins and macros](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/office-shared-vba/articles/how-autosave-impacts-addins-and-macros)

Comment: How does this apply to a userform?